# Monitor one server with two separate SCOM (opsmgr) consoles

Tags: scom

We have a situation where we have two independently deployed and managed SCOM consoles in our organization; both consoles are interested in collecting data from the same servers.

To the best of my knowledge, the OpsMgr agent can only send data to one server; it cannot 'serve two masters', so to speak.

However, I'm wondering if this could be accomplished by one console using agent-based monitoring, and the other using agentless monitoring?  I understand agentless monitoring comes with caveats in terms of permissiosn required to access the host, as well as certain monitoring packs not working with agentless monitoring, but perhaps it is a way to meet the need?

Thanks for any thoughts on this; it's probably not a very common configuration, and ideally we'd have both teams using the same console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To the best of my knowledge, the OpsMgr agent can only send data to
>   one server; it cannot 'serve two masters', so to speak.

Actually the agent can absolutely report to two different management groups. It's called "Agent Multihoming".

Basically you just find the agent in Add/Remove programs and modify the install, it will bring up a dialog that will allow you to add and remove the management servers that the agent reports to. You will have to remember to approve the agents in the management console of your second SCOM instance though.

Comment: you can also discover and "install" the agent from the second management group as usual and the agent will become multihomed on the second install.